# jQuery to delete hide table row if based on contents of two cells within row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to write a script for tampermonkey that hides a row in a table based on two conditions.

Condition 1: The cell in column 3 doesn't contain '/'

Condition 2: the cell in column 3 does contain '0:0'

I've got condition 1 working on its own with the following jQuery

`$("td:nth-of-type(3):not(:contains('/'))").parent ().hide ();`

and condition 2 with

`$("td:nth-of-type(3):contains('0:0')").parent ().hide ();`

but I haven't been able to combine them, I've tried the following:

`$("[td:nth-of-type(3):contains('0:0')][td:nth-of-type(3):not(:contains('/'))]").parent ().hide ();`

but no luck.  How can I combine the conditions?  I've tried to include an if statement but haven't been able to get that working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were heading in the right direction. Keep chaining the `:contains` and `:not(:contains(...))` calls.

Try the runnable example below, note that the 1st and 4th rows are hidden.

```js
$("td:nth-of-type(3):contains('0:0'):not(:contains('/'))").parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td> 0:0 </td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>123//</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>/ 0:0</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>0:0</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>0:0/</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```